# Moving items in ActiveRecord_Relation result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, activerecord-relation

I want to be able to return `User.all` with `current_user` as the first result, and the rest sorted alphabetically by `user.name`.

What's the "Rails" way to do this? I think it's to convert the ActiveRecord_Relation to an array and then use a combo of `.insert` and `.delete_at` to move the target User from its current position to the front. Would I want to create a helper method for that? Or is there a completely different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: The question which need to be asked: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @BroiSatse I want a select dropdown of all users with the current user at the top of the list...

Comment: I would re ask "Why?" but how about something like a fill field and an ajax call instead? As they type, it searches for a username. Or maybe some sort of lazy load would work. But I am curious as to why you would want that. Is this an admin page?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most "railsy" way, but this should work:

```
users  = User.all.append(User.find(current_user.id))
users = (users & users).reverse!
```

Comment: you can use "prepend" instead of "append" and avoid the "reverse" :-)

Answer (score 1):

In one query:

`users = User.where("id != ?", current_user.id).all.insert(0, User.find(current_user.id))`

However, please remember that it's almost always a bad idea to build your site around `User.all` queries... after 10,000+ users your app will grind to a halt.  Wherever you are doing this query you should paginate the results.